# Change default behaviour of Windows Combobox /Dropdown Win Forms C#

Tags: c#, combobox, drop-down-menu

I need to make sure that the combobox popsup instead of popping down. as this dropdown is placed at the bottom of the form it doesn't looks good when it drops down.

any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a desktop application or a web application?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using the standard dropdownlist control.

Also this is against what the user expects when he clicks on the control. It would be a better idea to change the design.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behaviour. It depends on how many items are shown in your dropdown. and where the browser window is situated on your screen. E.g. try amazon.com and drag the screen to the bottom and choose something from the search: the items will go up instead of down.

Was there something I missed?

Comment: I am having this dropdown in Windows Form Application. When I maximize the Form the dropdown/combobox popus up istead of down. I just need the same behaviour when form is not in maximized mode

Comment: It is not dependant on whether the form is maximized, but rather how close to the edge of the screen it is.

Answer (score 0):

Combobox will drop up if it is about to go over the screen's edge (so not your form's). I think that is a behaviour expected by many users, please specify why would you want it to go up all the time.

Comment: I want it to go up all the time coz its placed at the bottom of the form and when it drop down from there it crosses the boundary of the form which doesn't looks good

Answer (score 0):

To be frank, looking perfect doesn't matter nearly as much as your users having a consistent experience between your application and every other Windows application on earth.

People are trained to expect the combo box to work in a particular way, and if you change that even subtly it can be a jarring experience.